# Install ReactJS without internet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have to dev an ReactJS App on a specific computer which don't have any Internet access.

I used an Internet computer to try ReactJS. I followed this installation :

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

> npm install -g create-react-app
>
> create-react-app hello-world
>
> cd hello-world
>
> npm start

It downloaded me a lot of JS lib, but it worked ! Got my App and can dev.

Problem is, that without internet access, npm is not working to create my React seed.
I have no idea how to install React without internet access.

My goal is to implement an ReactJS app, with the lightest JS lib. I really have to make an "small app".

Is there any solutions ?
Transfer file from PC A -> PC B is, obv, not working.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I'm not sure, but as far as I know, there is no way to install packages from the npm registry without an internet connection. You would probably have to connect at least once.

Comment: You can't install via NPM without internet, but you can manually download packages, transfer them, then install them.

Comment: And is there any solutions to install ReactJS without ... npm ? ;/

Comment: create-react-app does a lot of the magic for you. The alternative is downloading all the individual libraries and putting it all together yourself, but that of course still requires an internet connection. I think what @eshansingh1 said is a good idea. Connect once, create the react app and if necessary zip/copy/whatever to your not-internet-connected computer so that you can dev locally.

Comment: Why do you not have internet access?

Comment: `Transfer file from PC A -> PC B is, obv, not working` then what were you going to do with your app once its done, if you can't transfer files from one computer to another anywa?

Comment: Professional reasons.

I'm going to use an Debian VM to create an 'create-react-app', and try to package all this dependencies.
I'll copy it to no acces computer, and pray.